# How to use internal expat XML parser in android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I want to use native expat parser instead of other parsers implemented in java.
Here is an [example](https://github.com/android/platform_external_expat/blob/master/examples/elements.c). But I got an error saying  `expat.h` could not be found.

Well, I am able to ndk-build expat parser once included with sources, but I really would like to use built-in expat rather than reinventing the wheel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you already found a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: nah, I gave up messing up with expat for a while, till dont know when.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem, I just copied the libexpat.so from my Android device (/system/lib/) to my NDK toolchain $NDK_PATH/lib. I also copied the the expat.h and expat_external.h from the expat sources to my NDK toolchain $NDK_Path/include. Now my ./configure scripts works.